Gatsby Script API increases total blocking time
I used https://pagespeed.web.dev/ today and was surprised that my website has only a performance score of 64. Running it in my browser, on the hosted site, in an incognito tab it's always between 95-100. Those are the metrics:

830ms TBT is very bad. In my own lighthouse run it's 0ms.

One issue is the Main-Thread Blocking Time. To my understanding this means loading those scripts will block the site from rendering. For example this is how I load the mtcatpcha stuff:
<Script src="https://service.mtcaptcha.com/mtcv1/client/mtcaptcha.min.js"></Script>
<Script src="https://service2.mtcaptcha.com/mtcv1/client/mtcaptcha2.min.js"></Script>
<div className="mtcaptcha"></div>

By default it should use the strategy post-hydrate. The docs says this:

The advantage of this strategy is that you have the ability to declare that your script should start loading after hydration. This is impactful because hydration is what makes your page interactive, and by using regular  tags (even with async or defer applied), you run the risk of your script being loaded in parallel with the framework JavaScript that hydrates your page.


This can have negative implications for key web vital metrics like Total Blocking Time. By leveraging the  component with the post-hydrate strategy, you ensure that your script avoids interfering with your page reaching an interactive state, resulting in a better experience for your users.

As far as I understand all of this the script API should not have an impact on Main-Thread Blocking Time. Is there an issue on my side?

I also tried adding those scripts after 3 seconds once react has hydrated and it still doesn't had any effect. Without those scripts included I score at 96 for performance

The local lighthouse data is different from the pagespeed.web.dev report because the latest pulls data from real users, which is quite useful since some customers may have slower devices or different network conditions.
Now that we know that real LCP is ~4s I think it's worth looking at the rendering flow from LCP perspective, since it might not necessarily be bad because of render-blocking requests.
I would suggest the following steps:

Identify what LCP element is (btw, it might be multiple elements on the same page depending on the resolution/device type/how fast user interacts with the page - but whatever lighthouse reports is usually good enough start);

Identify which requests load data that is required to show the LCP element (for example, you may need to send "GET /profile" request to load customer data and avatar URL) (to find this requests you can look at all requests that are happening during the "resource load delay" lcp phase in case LCP is an image, or "element render delay" if LCP is a text node)

Identify which JS files are making those requests (you can use devtools->network tab "initiator" column)

Measure TTFB (since that time shows how fast initial page structure is delivered - nothing happens before that unless you are using 103 early hints header), and see if that should be improved


Given that you are using Gatsby I would assume reasonable target metrics would be:

TTFB <500ms (that's the phase when initial HTML is loaded, since it's static it should be connection time + light server latency overhead);
Resource load delay <1s
Resource load duration <200ms
Element render delay <200ms

And in case LCP is a text element, they should look like this:

TTFB <500ms
Element render delay <1s

In total that should give <2s LCP, which is considered to be a good result :)
Let me know how this distribution looks like in your case and we can debug further together!
You might find this useful:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/overview#live-metrics

